# Using the fact this equation is equidimensional. Calculate all associated eigenvalues.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let

$$x^2y''+xy'+\lambda y=0,\,\,\,\,\,y(1)=0,\,\,y(b)=0\tag1$$

Using the fact this equation is equidimensional. Calculate all associated eigenvalues.

Is $\lambda=0$ an eigenvalue?

Prove there exist infinite eigenvalues with one minimum, but there doesn't exist a maximum eigenvalue.

**My attempt:**

Note the equation $(1)$ is a  Cauchy-Euler equation.

Suppose $y=x^r$ then $y'=r x^{r-1}$, $y''=r(r-1)x^{r-2}$.

Then

$$x^2r(r-1)x^{r-2}+xr x^{r-1}+r x^r=0\implies(r^2-r)x^r=0\iff r_1=0,\,\,\, r_2=-1$$

Then the solution for the ODE is:
$$y(x)=C_1+C_2x^{-1}$$

Here I'm a little confused, to solve my problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't use $x^\lambda$, use $x^r$ where $r$ is to be determined (it won't be $\lambda$).

Comment: Ok, i go to edit that @RobertIsrael

Comment: Using $\lambda$ for the power was the source of your confusion. The equation should be $r^2+\lambda=0$

Comment: Ummm, yes you have reason. I go to solve that and update my question. @Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering

$$
\left(x^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+x\frac{d}{dt}+\lambda\right)y = 0
$$

after the substitution $y = x^r$ we get

$$
x^r\left(r(r-1)+r +\lambda\right)=0
$$

then

$$
r = \pm i \sqrt\lambda
$$

then for $\lambda > 0$ we have

$$
y = C_1\sin(\sqrt\lambda \ln x) + C_2\cos(\sqrt\lambda \ln x) 
$$

and now from the boundary conditions

$$
y(1) = C_2 = 0\\
y(b) = C_1\sin(\sqrt\lambda \ln b) = 0
$$

then we conclude

$$
\sqrt\lambda\ln b = k \pi\Rightarrow \lambda_ k = \frac{\pi^2}{\ln^2 b}k^2
$$